# Iterate over JSON object with children

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, fancytree

I'm using fancytree to send data via ajax.

```
$("#save").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree").rootNode;
            var data = tree.toDict(true);
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.ajax(
            { 
                type: "POST",
                data :  { "data": data },
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#alert').empty().append(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

The JSON data is the follwing format. I need to reiterate over the following JSON object inorder to manipulate the data.

```
{
"expanded":true,
"key":"root_1",
"selected":false,
"title":"root",
"children":
[
    {"key":"p_1","selected":false,"title":"Animal Meat"},
    {"key":"p_2","selected":false,"title":"Animal Product"},
    {"folder":true,"key":"p_3","selected":false,"title":"Beverage","children":  
    [
        {"key":"2","selected":false,"title":"Tea"},
        {"key":"3","selected":false,"title":"Coffee"},
        {"key":"4","selected":false,"title":"Water"}
    ]},
    {"folder":true,"key":"p_4","selected":true,"title":"Cereal","children": 
    [
        {"key":"6","selected":true,"title":"Porridge"}
    ]},
    {"folder":true,"key":"p_5","selected":false,"title":"Dairy Product","children":
    [
        {"key":"7","selected":false,"title":"Cheese"},
        {"key":"8","selected":false,"title":"Curd"},
        {"key":"10","selected":false,"title":"Milk"},
    ]}
]}
```

The following function in Laravel handles this request.

```
public function storePreference(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->getContent();

        $data = urldecode($data);

        foreach($data['children'] as $child)
        {
           $key      = $child['key'];
            $selected = $child['selected'];
            $title    = $child['title'];

            printf("Key: %s, selected: %s, title: %s\n", $key, $selected ? "true" : "false", $title);
        }
    }
```

I need the following output:

```
Key: p_1, selected: false, title: Animal Meat
Key: p_2, selected: false, title: Animal Product
Key: p_3, selected: false, title: Beverage
Key: 2, selected: false, title: Tea
Key: 3, selected: false, title: Coffee
Key: 4, selected: false, title: Water
Key: p_4, selected: true, title: Cereal
Key: 6, selected: true, title: Porridge
Key: p_5, selected: false, title: Dairy Product
and so on...
```

I am using fancytree to send this data in Laravel 5.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Sorry, I have added more details now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = <<<JSON
{
"expanded":true,
"key":"root_1",
"selected":false,
"title":"root",
"children":
[
    {"key":"p_1","selected":false,"title":"Animal Meat"},
    {"key":"p_2","selected":false,"title":"Animal Product"},
    {"folder":true,"key":"p_3","selected":false,"title":"Beverage","children":  
    [
        {"key":"2","selected":false,"title":"Tea"},
        {"key":"3","selected":false,"title":"Coffee"},
        {"key":"4","selected":false,"title":"Water"}
    ]},
    {"folder":true,"key":"p_4","selected":true,"title":"Cereal","children": 
    [
        {"key":"6","selected":true,"title":"Porridge"}
    ]},
    {"folder":true,"key":"p_5","selected":false,"title":"Dairy Product","children":
    [
        {"key":"7","selected":false,"title":"Cheese"},
        {"key":"8","selected":false,"title":"Curd"},
        {"key":"10","selected":false,"title":"Milk"}
    ]}
]}
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data['children'] as $child) {
    $key      = $child['key'];
    $selected = $child['selected'];
    $title    = $child['title'];

    printf("Key: %s, selected: %s, title: %s\n", $key, $selected ? "true" : "false", $title);
}
```

This will output:

```
Key: p_1, selected: false, title: Animal Meat
Key: p_2, selected: false, title: Animal Product
Key: p_3, selected: false, title: Beverage
Key: p_4, selected: true, title: Cereal
Key: p_5, selected: false, title: Dairy Product
```

**Update:** I have modified the JSON in my example, because the JSON from the original post was invalid at the time of this writing (for example: the second to last line in the original JSON contained a trailing comma).

The Laravel method:

```
public function storePreference(Request $request)
{
    $dataString = $request->getContent();
    $dataString = urldecode($data);
    $dataString = json_decode($dataString, 'data=');

    $data = json_decode($dataString, true);

    foreach($data['children'] as $child)
    {
       $key      = $child['key'];
        $selected = $child['selected'];
        $title    = $child['title'];

        printf("Key: %s, selected: %s, title: %s\n", $key, $selected ? "true" : "false", $title);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting ErrorException:
Illegal string offset 'children'

Comment: I assume that has to do with the JSON which is present in your original post, because it is invalid. For example in the second last line, you have a trailing comma, which is invalid in JSON. (Please compare the JSON from your post with the JSON from my answer)

Comment: The comma was a mistake on my part. 
Your code is working perfectly fine else where. However, its not working here. Any idea what the "Illegal string offfset" error means?

Comment: There is also a comma to much in the line ending with "Milk" (third to last line), could you remove that and check if it works then, please?

Comment: The additional commas are mistakes on my part while trying to copy paste. I have added the full var_dump. Please do check and see where I am making mistake.

Comment: Here is a good site where you can paste in your JSON and it tells you if there are any problems http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The dump you posted is perfectly valid (excluding the "data=" prefix") and it worked with the code snippet from my answer. I don't know Laravel too well, but if you are working inside the `storePreference` method, have you replaced `$data = urldecode($data);` with `$data = json_decode($data, true);`? `urldecode()` is not needed here.

Comment: JSON is fine and your code is also working fine. The issue is somewhere in my Laravel code. Do I need to use json_decode but doing so is returning NULL.

Comment: Without urldecode the data looks someting like :string(4744) "data=%7B%22expanded%22%3Atrue%2C%22key%22%3A%22root_1%22%2C%22selected%22%3Afalse%2C%22title%22%3A%22root%22%2C%22children%22%3A%5.....

Comment: Okay, I think we are getting to it :). You are right, keep the `urldecode()` and please try this: `$dataString = ltrim(urldecode($data), 'data='); $data = json_decode($dataString, true);` (I will update my answer accordingly)

Comment: I just figured this out and have answered :). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How do I go the next level below?
foreach ($child['children'] as $c) 
      {
       $key      = $c['key'];
       $selected = $c['selected'];
       $title    = $c['title'];
          printf("<p>Key: %s, selected: %s, title: %s\n", $key, $selected ? "true" : "false", $title);

      }

Comment: figured it out as I need to add "if (isset($child['children'])) " as there are some nodes without children. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove the "data=" from $data string and use json_decode.

```
public function storePreference(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->getContent('data');

        $data = urldecode($data);
        $data = substr($data, 5);
        $data = json_decode($data, true);
        foreach($data['children'] as $child)
        {
            $key      = $child['key'];
            $selected = $child['selected'];
            $title    = $child['title'];

            printf("<p>Key: %s, selected: %s, title: %s\n", $key, $selected ? "true" : "false", $title);

            if (isset($child['children'])) 
            {
                foreach ($child['children'] as $c) 
                {
                    $key      = $c['key'];
                    $selected = $c['selected'];
                    $title    = $c['title'];
                    printf("<p>Key: %s, selected: %s, title: %s\n", $key, $selected ? "true" : "false", $title);

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks to @jeromegamez for the help.